# Display contents of object/array from sql object

Tags: php, sql

I want to be able to output this on screen, however can't seem to do so. I have stored the result of a sql statement in the variable result, I believe the statement returns an object.

```
$result = $application->nutrientsTotals($_SESSION['clubid'],"Greens",$year);
var_dump($result);
```

The output of the `var_dump()` is,

```
array(1) {
          [0]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) {
              ["Sum(`productsapplied`.n)"]=> float(5.58) 
              ["Sum(`productsapplied`.p)"]=> float(0)
              ["Sum(`productsapplied`.k)"]=> float(0) 
              ["Sum(`productsapplied`.mg)"]=> float(0.72)
          }
}
```

I have tried `` echo $result[0]["Sum(`productsapplied`.mg)"] `` and a few other things.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$result` contains an array of objects, so you'd need to access them like `$result[0]->var` - but you're better off changing your `nutrientsTotal()` method so it returns friendlier names.

Comment: how would i change `"Sum(`productsapplied`.mg)"` to say `n` ? As the name is simply part of the select statement from the query

Comment: Post your nutrientsTotal() method code, you need to modify your SQL to you end up with something like `SELECT SUM(productsapplied.n) AS n`

Comment: 'SELECT Sum(`productsapplied`.n), Sum(`productsapplied`.p), Sum(`productsapplied`.k), Sum(`productsapplied`.mg) FROM `productsapplied` JOIN `applications` ON `productsapplied`.applicationId = `applications`.id WHERE `applications`.area = ? AND `applications`.clubid = ? AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `applications`.date) = ? ',array($area,$id,$year)); SO im gussing would be like, select sum(....) as n, sum(...) as p ..?

Comment: Yep - and then you should be able to access that data through `$result[0]->n`, `$result[0]->p` etc.